# How can I tell when the animateLayoutChanges has completed?

Tags: android, animation, android-linearlayout

I'm taking advantage of the automated (built-in) animation of LinearLayout by adding `animateLayoutChanges` to the XML.

That works nicely.

However, when I attach on `Animation.AnimationListener` to that LinearLayout it never fires. So, I'm confused as to what listener I should be attaching and maybe what I should be attaching it to, in order to find out when a given transitional animation has completed.

So.. what I have is this:

```
       LinearLayout productsList = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.pList);

       productsList.setLayoutAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            Log.d(TAG, "animation started");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Log.d(TAG, "animation ended");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            Log.d(TAG, "animation repeated");
        }
    });
```

The animation plays as expected but none of my Logs are ever written.

Do I have to append my own custom animation to the layout for this to work, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
productsList.getLayoutTransition().addTransitionListener(new LayoutTransition.TransitionListener() {
    @Override
    public void startTransition(LayoutTransition transition, ViewGroup container, View view, int transitionType) {

    }

    @Override
    public void endTransition(LayoutTransition transition, ViewGroup container, View view, int transitionType) {

    }
});
```

Comment: fascinating. This is definitely a step in the right direction, but I notice that endTransition is fired multiple times (seemingly in connection with the number of items in the parent layout) but I'm not clear on the rhyme or reason. Do you happen to know how I can tell when it's actually *done with the transition?

Comment: Try to check transitionType value. This is a doc: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html

Comment: I checked this. Each startTransition is paired with endTransition. You can increase/decrease a counter to detect end of last transition.